# redux epic fires only once

Tags: react-redux, rxjs, redux-observable

I saw a related post about this issue, but my set up is a little different, so I don't have a solution yet.

I have this action creator and epic:

```
export const postToSendEmail = (emailBody: any) => ({ type: EMAIL.POST_EMAIL, payload: emailBody });

export const sendEmailEpic = (action$: any) => action$.pipe(
  ofType(EMAIL.POST_EMAIL),
  mergeMap((action: any) =>
    return Observable.ajax({
        url: "http://...",
        body: action.payload,
        ...
    }).flatMap(() => of(sendEmailDone()))
  ),
  catchError((error: any, source: any) => {
    // this doesn't work
    of(handleError(error));
    // this restarts the epic
    return source;
  })
);
```

In a react component, I have a button that just calls the actionCreator:

```
<button onClick={this.sendEmail}>send email</button>

sendEmail() {
    this.props.dispatch(postToSendEmail({ test: "test" }));
}
```

Clicking the button the first time works fine, and I see the api call in the Network, but clicking it a second time never fires. Why is that?

EDIT:

I updated the catch, but now, how do I dispatch the action I need? Using of(handleError) doesn't seem to actually call it.

Comment: Is there any error during your ajax call, or inside your code? If there is an error that is not catched, it might kill your entire epics. Are you able to execute call other epcis? Check this link for more details: https://github.com/redux-observable/redux-observable/issues/94

Comment: @Anas yes it does throw an error. I'm testing the catchError case, so i this case, the API returns a 404 so it hits the handleError function. Short version is, I'm allowing users to retry this when it fails, so that's why I need them to be able to fire it a second time.

Comment: Also, the way I have my epics set up is a little different from that article. I just have something like: const rootEpic = combineEpics(...); export default rootEpic; --> Then in the store setup, I did: epicMiddleware.run(rootEpic); -- So I'm not sure where that catch would go?

Comment: Okay, I figured out how to integrate it with my existing code. I updated it above, but now I'm facing another issue in how to do a dispatch call in the catchError.

Comment: Have a look at the [`rxjs-no-unsafe-catch`](https://github.com/cartant/rxjs-tslint-rules#rxjs-no-unsafe-catch) rule in `rxjs-tslint-rules`.

Comment: @cartant Thanks. That seems like a nice rule to add. But then how do I catch and log the error?

Comment: Make sure the `catchError` is within your `mergeMap`, that's all. Paul's article deals with NgRx, but the principle is the same: https://medium.com/@P_Lessing/handling-errors-in-ngrx-effects-a95d918490d9

Comment: @cartant That worked. Thanks! So just to clarify since I'm not too familiar with this, I don't want to add a `catchError` outside of `mergeMap` ever? To me, it sounds like that's just ignoring errors so I usually have a catch inside and outside.

Comment: With the redux-observable epic in your code, there's nothing 'outside' of the `mergeMap` that can effect any kind of error you can be expected to deal with.

Comment: Gotcha, so it's more-or-less useless to have that outside catch? I started adding a `wrapEpic` function from a suggestion made in the link Anas posted, but it doesn't seem like that should be needed either. That function just wraps `combineEpics` to catch any errors and return `source`.